# le coin gourmand -- grammatical analysis

Tags: grammaire

Example:

> le coin gourmand

Could you please break this phrase down for me in terms of grammar? Here's how much I understand. *le* is the definite article that goes with the noun *coin* which means *corner*. *gourmand* is a noun that can roughly be translated to English as *foodie*. Though English does have the same exact word in its vocabulary as somewhat a high-end word (probably hardly ever used in daily conversation), I'm nevertheless gonna go with the simpler *foodie*. So, how do you think the two are actually tied up together grammatically? And what would your translation of the entire phrase be?

It's at the bottom-right corner of the picture, right under the McDonald's sign. To zoom in, just click on the picture to open it in a new browser window.

[image: Levi, Quebec]

Comment: In your example, `gourmand` is used as an adjective, not a noun... , I would translate it as "The eating corner" or "The food corner"

Comment: Just so you know, I hear the word "gourmand" quite a lot in daily conversations. It is not as high-end as it seems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gourmand is usually an adjective, see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gourmand#French) for example.

Therefore the grammatical construct is really simple:

> Article + Noun + Adjective that applies to the noun before it

An okay translation would be for me:

> The gourmet corner